# Crystal Reports Installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I have the following installed on my server

Crystal Reports Basic Runtime for Visual Studio 2008
and
Crystal Reports for .Net Framework 2.0 (x86)

I am moving to a new server. The old server is Windows Server 2003. The new Server is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard (64 bits)

I want to install the same or equivalent software on my new machine so my software will continue to run. I don't think I need any licenses. Please point me to where I can download the installs

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a good poin to start
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824
the is ll the type of setup, you need the runtime i think.

Comment: This was the location of the correct download. Thanks, this has stumped me for weeks.